# How to change display message in an ExtJs Combobox?

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4, multi-select

I have an ExtJs Combobox with multiple true and I want to show "X values selected" on the input field instead of "Value 1, Value 2, Value 3". I tried with select listener but when I set the value to the input field and then you call multicombo.getValue() it takes the value from the input field. I would need something like take the value from the valueField (a hidden input).

My code:

```
var multiCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: item.id,
    multiSelect: true,
    displayField: 'name',
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'id',
    emptyText: 'Select',
    hiddenName: 'data[Model][' + item.getAttribute('question-id') + '][value]',
    submitValue: true,
    inputType: 'hidden',
    value: selectedOptions,
    width: 300,
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'local',
    listeners: {
        expand: function (combo) {
            var values = Ext.get(combo.hiddenDataEl.dom.lastChild).dom.value;
            values = values.split(",");
            Ext.each(values, function (value, i) {
                values[i] = parseInt(value);
            });
            combo.setValue(values);
            Ext.get(combo.getInputId()).dom.value = values.length + ' selected';
        },
        select: function (combo, values) {
            if (values[values.length - 1].data.id === parseInt(item.getAttribute('not-applicable'))) {
                combo.setValue(parseInt(item.getAttribute('not-applicable')));
            } else {
                var notApplicable = -1;
                var newValues = combo.getValue();
                if ((notApplicable = combo.getValue().indexOf(parseInt(item.getAttribute('not-applicable')))) != -1) {
                    newValues.splice(notApplicable, 1);
                }
                combo.setValue(newValues);
            }
            Ext.get(combo.hiddenDataEl.dom.lastChild).dom.value = combo.getValue().join(',');
            optionsSelected = combo.getValue();
            Ext.get(combo.getInputId()).dom.value = optionsSelected.length + ' selected';
        },
        change: function (combo) {
            if (item.getAttribute('required') == 'true') {
                if (combo.getValue().length == 0) {
                    question.findParentNode('li', 1, true).addCls("is_required");
                } else {
                    question.findParentNode('li', 1, true).removeCls("is_required");
                }
                //There is no ExtJs equivalent for this
                $('#' + combo.getInputId()).keyup();
            }
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I follow what is going on with all of the event handlers (so I may be missing something), but the simplest way to achieve what you described in your first sentence above is to provide your own implementation for the combo's `getDisplayValue` method. [Here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-method-getDisplayValue) it is in the docs.

Just set it up to return a count of how many values are selected. Here's an example:

```
var multiCombo = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    renderTo: item.id,
    multiSelect: true,
    displayField: 'name',

    // your own getDisplayValue implementation
    getDisplayValue: function() {
        return multiCombo.value.length + ' values selected';
    },

    editable: false,
    valueField: 'id',
    emptyText: 'Select',
    hiddenName: 'data[Model][' + item.getAttribute('question-id') + '][value]',
    submitValue: true,
    inputType: 'hidden',
    value: selectedOptions,
    width: 300,
    store: store,
    queryMode: 'local',
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this may help:

```
getDisplayValue: function() {
            return (this.displayTplData.length > 1) ? this.displayTplData.length + ' selected' : this.displayTplData[0].name;
        },
```